# Ejabberd WebAdmin password error

Tags: ejabberd

How to fetch or change Ejabberd WebAdmin password(running on localhost:5280,using windows-7,64bit ) as i think have forget that password,as i am trying this since 3 days.Its not working in my case please sort this out.